# Comparando apenas a data de campo DateTime no C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, comparação

Preciso comparar apenas a data de dois campos `DateTime`.

```
DateTime aux = new DateTime(2016, 09, 02, 10, 0, 0);
if (aux.Equals(DateTime.Now))
{
     //Alguma ação...
}
```

No código acima, preciso que entre no `if` quando a data (02/09/2016) for igual nos dois objetos. Nesse caso ele não entra porque o `Time` dos dois objetos é diferente. O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você deve pegar a propriedade Date do DateTime por exemplo

```
DateTime aux = new DateTime(2016, 09, 02, 10, 0, 0);
if (aux.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date))
{
     //Alguma ação...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do Marco Giovanni está correta, resolvi responder para colocar a forma idiomática:

```
var aux = new DateTime(2016, 09, 02, 10, 0, 0);
if (aux.Date == DateTime.Now.Date) {
    Console.WriteLine("Ok");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FI63xe). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6crEG). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Comparing.cs).